# lambda with condition in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, filter

Any way to improve the code with a better solution?

say in the list `nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, want to use `lambda` to do a simple calculation for `num%2 == 0` only as the following:

```
print map(lambda n:n**2, filter(lambda n: n%2!=0, nums))
```

Just wonder if any way to just use one lambda expression for it?

Comment: So you want the get the output: `[1, 9, 25]`?

Comment: you can use list compression `[ num * num for num in nums if num % 2 == 0 ]`

Comment: you mean `[ num * num for num in nums if num % 2 != 0 ]`

Comment: In CPython, it is best to avoid `map` and `filter` with non-builtin functions, and you should instead use the equivalent comprehsion construct.

Answer (score 3):

If you *really* want to use `lambda`, you can do it with one lambda that issues the squared value or 0 depending on the oddness of the input, using a ternary expression (but you still have to `filter` using `None` so only non-zero numbers are kept)

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
result = list(filter(None,map(lambda n:n**2 if n%2 else 0,nums)))
```

result:

```
[1, 9, 25]
```

note that `list` conversion is required only for python 3.

Of course, all those `filter`, `map`, ... chaining renders the `lambda` inefficient/not that useful. You'd be better off with a simple list comprehension.

```
result = [n**2 for n in nums if n%2]
```

`map` should be only needed when you have the function (or built-in) handy (like `map(str,my_list)` for instance). All those chained calls could be less performant than that simple list comprehension in the end.

A more detailed explanation here: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html#small-functions-and-the-lambda-expression

> Which alternative is preferable? That’s a style question; my usual course is to avoid using lambda.
>   One reason for my preference is that lambda is quite limited in the functions it can define. The result has to be computable as a single expression, which means you can’t have multiway if... elif... else comparisons or try... except statements. If you try to do too much in a lambda statement, you’ll end up with an overly complicated expression that’s hard to read.